# How to fix "Source file newer than byte-compiled file" error?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm getting the error

> Source file `~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824/cmake-mode.el' newer than byte-compiled file

when I attempt to open a CMakeLists.txt file in cmake-mode.

My .emacs consists (in part) of the following:

```
(setq load-path (cons 
             (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/cmake-mode-20110824") 
             load-path))
(require 'cmake-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("CMakeLists\\.txt\\'" . cmake-mode)
            ("\\.cmake\\'" . cmake-mode))
              auto-mode-alist))
```

The backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument char-table-p nil)
  char-table-parent(nil)
  cmake-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(cmake-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer CMakeLists.txt> "~/CMakeLists.txt" nil nil   "~/CMakeLists.txt" (19923691 2049))
  find-file-noselect("~/CMakeLists.txt" nil nil t)
  find-file("~/CMakeLists.txt" t)
  call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
```

I'm confused by why this error is occurring. Disclaimer: I am an emacs and elisp noob.

Comment: You're disclaimer is redundant since "Source file newer..." is a warning and not an error:)

Comment: It's an error to me, damn it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably within your `cmake-mode` which is quite outdated.
Here's how to fix it:

1. Remove all your setup from above
2. Make sure that you have `emacs24`
3. In your `~/.emacs`:

   ```
   (package-initialize)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
   ```
4. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-list-packages`. Find `cmake-mode` with <kbd>C-s</kbd>.
   Mark for installation with <kbd>i</kbd> and install with <kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: If the `add-to-list` is needed, it's a bug in cmake-mode.el.

Comment: Indeed, this was fixed recently.

Comment: Also, you might want to set `load-prefer-newer` to a non-nil value to avoid loading outdated byte code files in future.